Cloud Function deploy error in Flutter (JavaScript)
I want to send a welcome email to the user when logging in to Google using Cloud Functions in Flutter Web, and save the user information to FireStore. I want to create a separate admin and project in the future to manage it directly. Currently, Google login is possible, but Cloud Function deployment is not possible. Below is the Cloud Function code written in JS.
Please let me know what the problem is.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "myID@gmail.com",
    pass: "myPW",
  }
});

exports.onUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  try {
    console.log('User object:', user);
    
    if (!user) {
      console.error('User object is undefined');
      return;
    }

    
    await admin.firestore().collection('auth_users').doc(user.uid).set({
      email: user.email || '',
      displayName: user.displayName || '',
      photoURL: user.photoURL || '',
      createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      lastLoginAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });

    
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'myID@gmail.com',
      to: user.email,
      subject: 'welcome!',
      text: `Hi, ${user.displayName || ''},`
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Welcome email sent to:', user.email);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in onUserCreated:', error);
  }
});

Below is the error message
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myproject/Documents/project/test002/functions/index.js:18:40)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at loadModule (/Users/myproject/Documents/project/test002/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js:40:16)
    at loadStack (/Users/myproject/Documents/project/test002/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js:157:23)
    at /Users/myproject/Documents/project/test002/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/bin/firebase-functions.js:56:56


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

And I would also appreciate it if you could let me know if coding cloud functions in Python would result in fewer errors.

The error message says the problem is on line 18, which uses functions.auth.user().  That suggests functions might not be what you think it is.  Which version of the firebase-functions module are you using?

the version is "firebase-functions": "^6.0.1", "firebase-admin": "^12.6.0"

Can you try using imports as firebase-functions/v1 ? Also consider using typescript for firebase functions which could catch these errors while development itself.
